# Rendering custom templates for django-registration-redux

Tags: django, django-templates, django-registration

I have saved the required templates for django-registration-redux in to my project folder template/registration/ (e.g. registration_form.html)

When I run the registration module, it continues to reference the templates in the django-registration-redux. How do I use my own custom template without modifying the module.

I looked at the backend for django-registration-redux and it points to template/registration/registration_form.html.  I'm not sure what I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) says

> To fix this, make sure that in the INSTALLED_APPS of your settings.py
>   the entry for the registration app is placed above
>   django.contrib.admin.

Maybe that helps?